# How to force orientation rotation from UINavigationController subclass?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

When subclassing `UINavigationController`, how would one force a device rotation on a view controller that has already been pushed onto the stack? The problem I am trying to solve is that if a view controller is pushed onto the stack when in portrait mode, for example, that view controller will only pop in portrait mode even if the device has rotated to landscape. Therefore, how would one force the destination view controller (during a pop transition) to rotate its orientation?

The following code is from the custom pop transition animation which is where the forced orientation change would take place.

```
...

guard let fromViewController = topViewController,
    let toViewController = previousViewController else {

    return

}

...

// force rotation before popping
if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {

    // this does not work
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    toViewController.setValue(value, forKey: "supportedInterfaceOrientations")

} else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft {

    // force toViewController into landscape left

} else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {

    // force toViewController into landscape right

}

// begin pop animation
...
```